# Improving $I(m) < 2$, if $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $p$

Tags: number-theory, upper-lower-bounds, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

The topic of [odd perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) likely needs no introduction.

Let $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$ denote the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$, and let $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$ denote the *abundancy index* of $x$.  Suppose that there exists a (hypothetical) odd perfect number $N = p^k m^2$ with special prime $p$ satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.

In this [paper](https://www.mililink.com/issue_content.php?id=62&iId=319&vol=6&is=3&mon=December&yer=2016&pg=95-121) (page $112$), it is stated that:

> An improvement to the currently known upper bound of $I(m) < 2$ will be considered a major breakthrough.  In the [sequel (?)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.2329), a *viable approach* towards improving the inequality $I(m) < 2$ will be presented, which may necessitate the use of ideas from  the paper [by Ward](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0806.1001v2.pdf).

I revisited the argument(s) in the sequel, and there was no mention of a specific connection to Ward's ideas.

So here I go now:  Suppose $10$ divides $m^2$.  (This is actually a *false* assumption, but oh well.)

Then $$\frac{9}{5} = I(10) \leq I(m^2).$$

Now, here is where it becomes *very interesting*.  Take the contrapositive of the last statement.

**Suppose that $I(m^2) < 9/5$.  Then $10$ does not divide $m^2$.**

Note that the conclusion "$10$ does not divide $m^2$" of the contrapositive is true (since $m$ is odd).

> Notice that, if $I(m^2) < 9/5$ were true, then we would have
> $$\dfrac{2(p-1)}{p} < I(m^2) < \dfrac{9}{5} \iff 10(p - 1) < 9p \iff p < 10 \implies p = 5$$
> and
> $$I(m) < I(m^2) < \dfrac{9}{5}.$$

Here is my:

> **INITIAL QUESTION:** Since it is known that $I(m^2) > 8/5$, will it be possible to prove that the upper bound $I(m^2) < 9/5$ holds?

**MY ATTEMPT**

Suppose that $I(m^2) > 9/5$.  But we have
$$\dfrac{2p}{p+1} \geq I(m^2) > \dfrac{9}{5},$$
which implies that
$$10p > 9p + 9$$
$$p > 9$$
$$p \geq 13 \implies I(p^k) < \dfrac{p}{p - 1} \leq \dfrac{13}{12} \implies I(m^2) = \dfrac{2}{I(p^k)} > \dfrac{24}{13} > \dfrac{9}{5}.$$

Hence, we have the biconditional
$$I(m^2) > \dfrac{9}{5} \iff p \geq 13,$$
so that, in order to prove $I(m^2) < 9/5$, we need to rule out $p \geq 13$.

> **FINAL QUESTION:** Has anyone actually conjectured in the literature that $p = 5$?  (Pace Nielsen says in [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/48236/10365) that, even if $p = 5$ and $k = 1$, there are no known effective bounds on $N$.)