# Does this "improvement" to $I(m) < 2$, if $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $p$, work?

Tags: inequality, upper-lower-bounds, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers, open-problem

(Preamble:  This question is an offshoot of this [earlier post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4189622).)

Denote the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$ by $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$, and the *abundancy index* of $x$ by $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$.

Suppose that there exists a (hypothetical) odd perfect number $N = p^k m^2$ with special prime $p$ satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.

Since $p$ is prime, we have the formula and corresponding (sharp?) upper bound
$$I(p^k)=\dfrac{\sigma(p^k)}{p^k}=\dfrac{p^{k+1}-1}{p^k (p-1)}<\dfrac{p^{k+1}}{p^k (p - 1)}=\dfrac{p}{p-1}.$$
Moreover, since $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ holds, then $p \geq 5$.  This implies that
$$I(p^k)<\dfrac{p}{p-1} \leq \dfrac{5}{4}.$$
We therefore have
$$I(m^2)=\dfrac{2}{I(q^k)} > \dfrac{8}{5},$$
since the abundancy index function $I$ is *multiplicative*.

Here is my question:

> Can I then say that
> $$I(m^2) > \dfrac{8}{5} \geq I(m),$$
> since $I(m^2) > I(m)$ holds for all positive integers $m$?

**MY ATTEMPT**

I was thinking that I could use the fact that
$$\inf{I(m^2)} = \dfrac{8}{5}$$
and then "deduce" as follows:
$$I(m) < I(m^2)$$
This implies (**?**) that
$$I(m) \leq \sup{I(m)} \leq \inf{I(m^2)} = \dfrac{8}{5}.$$

**MY SECOND ATTEMPT**

We have
$$\bigg(\dfrac{2(p-1)}{p}\bigg)^{\dfrac{\ln(4/3)}{\ln(13/9)}} < \bigg(I(m^2)\bigg)^{\dfrac{\ln(4/3)}{\ln(13/9)}} < I(m),$$
as communicated by Pascal Ochem in an e-mail dated **April 17, 2013**.

So *if* $I(m) \leq 8/5$, then we have the inequality
$$\bigg(\dfrac{2(p-1)}{p}\bigg)^{\dfrac{\ln(4/3)}{\ln(13/9)}} < \dfrac{8}{5},$$
which [results](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve+%282%28p+-+1%29%2Fp%29%5E%28ln%284%2F3%29%2Fln%2813%2F9%29%29+%3C+8%2F5+for+p) in the real solutions
$$p = 1$$
or
$$1 < p < \dfrac{2\exp\Bigg(\frac{\ln(8/5)\ln(9/13)}{\ln(4/3)}\Bigg)}{2\exp\Bigg(\frac{\ln(8/5)\ln(9/13)}{\ln(4/3)}\Bigg) - 1} \approx 11.3334$$

Since $p$ is the special prime (satisfying $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$), then $p = 5$.

I therefore predict that:

> **CONJECTURE:** If $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $p$, then $p = 5$.

**Alas, this is where I get stuck, as I have no proof of this conjecture.**